# How can group by or merge my json object based on common property in angular4 project

Tags: json, angular

I have this json object in my angular4 project. I want to group by or merge this object based on common property.

How can merge these object based on fixture_desc? I want to display as fixture_desc= "Pepsi Cooler" and under it all items.

```
 "items": [
              {
                "barcode": "052000324815",
                "price": 2,
                "taxable": false,
                "description": "Gatorade Cool Blue",
                "tax_rate": 0,
                "inventory": 8,
                "fixture_desc": "Pepsi Cooler"

              },
              {
                "barcode": "052000328660",
                "price": 2,
                "taxable": false,
                "description": "Gatorade Fruit Punch ",
                "tax_rate": 0,
                "inventory": 8,
                "fixture_desc": "Pepsi Cooler",
                "min": 2,
                "max": 8,
                "_id": "58feb29a3a5c560011b1b96c"
              },
              {
                "barcode": "052000328684",
                "price": 2,
                "taxable": false,
                "description": "Gatorade Lemon Lime ",
                "tax_rate": 0,
                "inventory": 4,
                "fixture_desc": "Pepsi Cooler",
                "min": 1,
                "max": 4,

              }
        ]
```

I want to make organise to display my data. My expected  result is like this :

```
"items": [
{
    "name": "Pepsi Cooler”,
    "items": [
    {
          "barcode": "052000324815",
          "price": 2,
          "taxable": false,
          "description": "Gatorade Cool Blue",
          "tax_rate": 0,
          "inventory": 8,
          "fixture_desc": "Pepsi Cooler"
        },
        {
          "barcode": "052000328660",
          "price": 2,
          "taxable": false,
          "description": "Gatorade Fruit Punch ",
          "tax_rate": 0,
          "inventory": 8,
          "fixture_desc": "Pepsi Cooler"

        }
    ]
}
{
    "name": “Cook Cooler”,
    "items": [
    {
          "barcode": "052000324815",
          "price": 2,
          "taxable": false,
          "description": "Gatorade Cool Blue",
          "tax_rate": 0,
          "inventory": 8,
          "fixture_desc": "Cook Cooler
        },
        {
          "barcode": "052000328660",
          "price": 2,
          "taxable": false,
          "description": "Gatorade Fruit Punch ",
          "tax_rate": 0,
          "inventory": 8,
          "fixture_desc": "Cook Cooler
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected result, please?

Comment: @Myonara I updated my question please check it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. I am posting it if its help anyone. 
Here my Array:

```
    var myobj={"items": [
                      {
                        "barcode": "052000324815",
                        "description": "Gatorade Cool Blue",
                        "fixture_desc": "Pepsi Cooler"
                      },
                      {
                        "barcode": "052000328660",
                        "description": "Gatorade Fruit Punch ",
                        "fixture_desc": "Pepsi Cooler",
                      },
                      {
                        "barcode": "052000328684",
                        "description": "Gatorade Lemon Lime ",
                        "fixture_desc": "Pepsi Cooler",
                      }
                ]
    }
    and this is my solution:
     result:any[] = [];
     finalResult(myObj:any){
                var Obj = myObj;
                var groups:any[]=[];
    for (let a of Obj) {
        groups[a.fixture_desc] = groups[a.fixture_desc] || {
                        name:a.fixture_desc,
                        items:[],
                        isfixtureExpanded:false
                    };
                    groups[a.fixture_desc].items.push({

                            barcode: a.barcode,
                            description: a.description,
                            fixture_desc:a.fixture_desc,

                    }); 
                }

         for (var key in groups){

            this.result.push(groups[key]);
        }
                }

console.log(this.result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking the code you can show us whatever you have done to achieve it, SO is not code generator. But anyway here's the code that can do the same you wanted.

```
function group(array, prop) {
var result = [];
    array.forEach(function(val) {
        var found = false;
        for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
            if(result[i].name === val[prop]) {
                result[i].items.push(val);
                found = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Call it as

```
var finalResult = group(items,'fixture_desc');
```